# Country picker in swift like clubhouse

Tags: swift, xcode, uipickerview, uipicker

I’m wondering is there any easiest way for me to implement country picker like clubhouse with image as well? i've research about some libraries on the GitHub, but can't find good one. do i have to make custom UIPickerView for each of them with image?

or is there any good one?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is a pod called *FlagPhoneNumber*. You can achiev same look as in Clubhouse if you little customize it or even without any pod customization if you just adjust font and view in your app using this pod. https://github.com/chronotruck/FlagPhoneNumber